# PHP DOM loadHtmlFile I/O exception

Tags: php, dom, html-parsing

I have the following code snippet - echo'ing $msn gives me the full html output as expected. However, the $dom->loadHTMLFile gives me an exception:

> Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile() [domdocument.loadhtmlfile]: I/O
>   warning : failed to load external entity

Not sure what i am doing wrong? Its a straightforward piece of code..

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();

$msn = file_get_contents("http://moneycentral.msn.com/");

echo $msn;
echo "<br><br>";

$html = $dom->loadHTMLFile($msn);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

loadHTMLFile takes a path to the file you're trying to load.  What you're actually doing is passing it the HTML markup as an argument.  Naturally, it fails.

You need to either do

```
$html = $dom->loadHTMLFile("http://moneycentral.msn.com/");
```

or

```
$html = $dom->loadHTML($msn);
```

Answer (score 2):

What you want is [`loadHTML`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) and not `loadHTMLFile`. The latter is to open a file, not the content of the file. The value of `$msn` contains the content, and not the URL to the file itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this construction:

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$html = $dom->loadHTMLFile($msn);
```